# Saving ResultSet to use as input for writing file

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I'm trying to save the `ResultSet` of a DB query into an `ArrayList` to be used as an input to write to a file but I run out of memory. There is about 116k rows of data in the table I'm reading. I've tried writing directly to the file inside the `readDB()` method and it creates a `CSV`-file of about 3.3 MB. This is my code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DBAccess dbAccess = new DBAccess();

    }
}
```

The class and method to read the DB.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBAccess {

    public List<String> readDB() {

        String url = "jdbc:Cobol://Dev/Project Files/DatAndCpyFiles";


        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
             Statement stmt = con.createStatement())

        {

            stmt.setFetchSize(10);

            Class.forName("com.hxtt.sql.cobol.CobolDriver").newInstance();


            String sql = "select * from PROFS";


            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

            ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int iNumCols = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= iNumCols; i++) {
                result.add(resultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(i) + ";");
            }
            String row;

            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= iNumCols; i++) {

                    row = rs.getString(i);

                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u0086", "å");
                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u008F", "Å");
                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u0084", "ä");
                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u008E", "Ä");
                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u0094", "ö");
                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u0099", "Ö");
                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u0081", "ü");
                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u009A", "Ü");
                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u0082", "é");
                    row = row == null ? " " : row.replaceAll("\u0090", "É");

                    result.add(result + row.trim() + ";");
                }
            }

            rs.close();
            System.out.println("Returning result");

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at se.spedweb.DBAccess.readDB(DBAccess.java:56)
    at se.spedweb.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

What other data structure can I for this? Am I using the wrong approach for this? I could just `append` to a file instead of `add` to list in the method but I thought it would be cleaner to have writing to file and reading the database in separate classes, maybe this is wrong.

Comment: Consider using a callback, pass a writer to the db reader (and call back to the writer with one row at a time). Then you have the actual write logic (serializing a row) separated from the read logic.

Comment: What is wrong here is trying to load entire result sets into memory.

Comment: `String sql = "select * from PROFS";` this might be wrong if values are more in underlying `PROFS`table

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not familiar with Callbacks. I had a quick look at Google but I'm not sure how to apply it here. What would a Callback look like roughly in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you run java with the command line option try using -Xmx, you can manually set the size of the heap. Try setting it to -Xmx2048m.
Note: there's ways to do it if your using an IDE, a quick google will show you how to change it